# Variable assignment within a "? :" if statement

Tags: perl

I'm wanting to reassign "$homologue" within a ? : statement and avoid using a flag to achieve this, i.e. do it directly. The output is "1" rather than AGFTVASTGHAVFEW--SAC. Help appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say switch);
my $homologue;
my $homologue_gap = "AGFTVASTGHAVFEW--SAC";
my $flag = 0;

$homologue_gap =~ m/-/ ? $homologue = $homologue_gap : $flag = 1; 
say $homologue;
__DATA__
**Output** 
1
**Output sought** 
AGFTVASTGHAVFEW--SAC
```

Background, I'm extracting homologous oligo-peptides within an alignment, and accounting for any indels that may be present (the "-" character).

Comment: The ?: is called a ternary or conditional operator.see docs: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator

Comment: Use `?:` to return a value (since it's an operator). If you have `?:` in void context, just use `if`/`else` instead; it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already inside a if/else statement where this code is used. I prefer to avoid nested if/else statements, because of the } else { .. followed by } else { syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least one more set of parentheses around `$flag = 1` -- `:` has higher precedence than `=`

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$a ? $b=1 : $c=2'
(($a ? ($b = 1) : $c) = 2);

$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$a ? $b=1 : ($c=2)'
(($a ? ($b = 1) : ($c = 2));
```

Comment: Thanks. When I'm less under the guilotene of a deadline I will look into Deparse, David Cross has suggested this in a different context.

Comment: Many thanks indeed. Now I've some time to look at this it is the neatest solution. In the jaws of a deadline I just didn't spot it. Deparse is very cool.

Answer (score 3):

You can be a bit clever with the `?:` operator

```
($homologue_gap =~ m/-/ ? $homologue : $flag) = ($homologue_gap =~ m/-/ ? $homologue_gap : 1);
```

Comment: Thank you :-). This is a direct cut and paste solution and yes you are defintely a bit cleverer than me.

Comment: That's horrible!!! It's very difficult to read/debug/maintain because you interspaced the parts that belong together (ABCABC instead of ABBCC).

Answer (score 2):

You have a precedence issue.

```
$homologue_gap =~ m/-/ ? $homologue = $homologue_gap : $flag = 1;
```

means

```
( $homologue_gap =~ m/-/ ? ( $homologue = $homologue_gap ) : $flag ) = 1;
```

but you want

```
$homologue_gap =~ m/-/ ? ( $homologue = $homologue_gap ) : ( $flag  = 1 );
```

This is not an appropriate use of the conditional operator. If you're not using the value it returns, it's much better (clearer) to use an `if` statement.

```
if ($homologue_gap =~ m/-/) { $homologue = $homologue_gap } else { $flag = 1 }
```

That said, this kind of pattern is quite rarely used. I suspect that something even clearer could be devised if we had access to the surrounding code.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand. Again the statement is within an If else statement and I wish to avoid too much nesting.

Comment: @Micheal G., That makes no sense sense; it's equally nested no matter which approach you take. And I repeat, I suspect you have some badly organized code to being with, and reorganizing the whole instead of just looking at this one line is what's going to make it more readable.

Comment: Right, but its a big "pipeline" and else else else becomes difficult to read, particularly when debugging and beta-testing over a lot of data. If its a single "if else", I like to keep it distinct and helps me keep my head "above" the flow of data.

Comment: A big pipeline of `?:` is many times worse. It's widely accepted that `?:` is only clear for the most trivial of cases. Since you bring up debugging, stepping through `?:` might not even be possible, and tracing the path through it difficult and error-prone.

Comment: I appreciate your point ?: can be overdone. In context its a single ?: within a "if else" loop, but a critical part of the code.  Most of the script is controlling data within a multidimensional hash. Context: this part of the script is the evolutionary homology of amino acid "indels" and the conditions when "a homologue" can be declared and this is subject to interpretation.

Comment: When I mentioned the context of the statement, I didn't mean the purpose of the program; I meant the actual code surrounding it. ("*the parts of something written or spoken that immediately precede and follow a word or passage and clarify its meaning.*")

Comment: Point accepted, but you know if I was happy being regular I'd code in Python ;-)

Comment: @MichaelG. ??? "Being regular" wasn't a reason I gave. Readability, debuggability, maintainability, lack of fragility were.